# Hibernate GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: hibernate, group-concat

I would love to make a simple query that brings all the names in one single cell, but it looks like GROUP_CONCAT is not understood by hibernate.

These are my entities:

Entity CitaExamen:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cita_examen")
@NamedQuery(name="CitaExamen.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM CitaExamen c")
public class CitaExamen implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String nombre;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="agrupacion_flujo_id")
    private AgrupacionFlujo agrupacionFlujo;

    public CitaExamen() {
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public AgrupacionFlujo getAgrupacionFlujo() {
        return agrupacionFlujo;
    }

    public void setAgrupacionFlujo(AgrupacionFlujo agrupacionFlujo) {
        this.agrupacionFlujo = agrupacionFlujo;
    }

}
```

Entity AgrupacionFlujo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "agrupacion_flujo")
@NamedQuery(name = "AgrupacionFlujo.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM AgrupacionFlujo t")
public class AgrupacionFlujo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "agrupacionFlujo", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<CitaExamen> citaExamenes;

    public AgrupacionFlujo() {
        citaExamenes = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<CitaExamen> getCitaExamenes() {
        return citaExamenes;
    }

    public void setCitaExamenes(Set<CitaExamen> citaExamenes) {
        this.citaExamenes = citaExamenes;
    }

    public CitaExamen addCitaExamen(CitaExamen citaExamen) {
        getCitaExamenes().add(citaExamen);
        citaExamen.setAgrupacionFlujo(this);

        return citaExamen;
    }

    public CitaExamen removeCitaExamen(CitaExamen citaExamen) {
        getCitaExamenes().remove(citaExamen);
        citaExamen.setAgrupacionFlujo(null);

        return citaExamen;
    }

}
```

Query without GROUP_CONCAT:

```
String hql =
"SELECT new AgrupacionFlujoRepoDTO(af.id, ce.nombre) "
+ "FROM AgrupacionFlujo af JOIN af.citaExamenes ce ";
```

Result:

1;First Name

1;Second Name

My wished query but with error the project doesn't run:

```
String hql =
"SELECT new AgrupacionFlujoRepoDTO(af.id, GROUP_CONCAT(ce.nombre)) "
+ "FROM AgrupacionFlujo af JOIN af.citaExamenes ce GROUP BY af.id";
```

Desired Result:

1;First Name, Second Name

Any idea on how to do it?